# Possible to add more ItemWriters to ClassifierCompositeItemWriter at runtime

Tags: spring-batch

ClassifierCompositeItemWriter allows us to choose which ItemWriter to use at runtime based on the value of something. For example..

```
public class CustomerClassifier implements
    Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<Customer>> {
    private ItemWriter<Customer> fileItemWriter;
    private ItemWriter<Customer> jdbcItemWriter;
    @Override
    public ItemWriter<Customer> classify(Customer customer) {
        if(customer.getState().matches("^[A-M].*")) {
            return fileItemWriter;
        } else {
            return jdbcItemWriter;
        }
    }
    public void setFileItemWriter(ItemWriter<Customer> fileItemWriter) {
        this.fileItemWriter = fileItemWriter;
    }
    public void setJdbcItemWriter(ItemWriter<Customer> jdbcItemWriter) {
        this.jdbcItemWriter = jdbcItemWriter;
    }
}
```

The decision here on what ItemWriters are possible is all done at compile time.

Is it possible to add more ItemWriter at runtime?

Comment: What if we add all ItemWriters and then decision drive from Customer object?

Comment: There could be thousands and they won't be know until runtime.  Basically the batch application takes a complex piece of tree like data and the filters into mutiple CSV files.

Comment: are you saying you have a thousand of writer beside fileItemWriter and jdbcItemWriter? If yes, we need to see back the design